# npm install peerDependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is there any way to install all `peerDependencies` in to a project that npm package is rely on?

Lets say I am installing `some-package` that has `peerDependencies` it is rely on.
So I want all `peerDependencies` of that package to be installed in to `npm_modules` and saved in to my `package.josn` file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Npm 3 and later does not install peerDependencies automatically and has no options to do it. You can install them manually one by one, do it with bash script or using npm package like `npm-install-peers`.